# Using $.fancybox.open with 1 param

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to use exactly `$.fancybox.open` and give to that function only 1 parameter where will be list of images and all needed options.

I mean like that:

```
$.fancybox.open(mygallery());
```

My problem is i don't want to use it like this:

```
$.fancybox.open(mygallery(), options);
```

Can the options be together with list of images in 1 parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all your gallery elements with different API options in a single variable that you can use as parameter within the `$.fancybox.open()` method like :

```
var param = [{
    // fancybox options first element
    href: "http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg",
    title: "the title",
    padding: 0,
    margin: [20, 100, 0, 0],
    afterShow: function () {
        alert("hello") // example of callback function
    }
}, {
    // fancybox options second element, etc.
    href: "http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg",
    title: "the second title",
    padding: 10,
    afterShow: function () {
        alert("the second") // example of callback function
    }
}];


$.fancybox.open(param);
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JQFGd/)**